# JWPlayer - Click to play interpreted as autoplay on iOS Safari/Chrome

Tags: ios, safari, jwplayer, autoplay, autostart

I'm working on a custom player built around a JWPlayer. When clicking the "Play" button, I first fetch the content asynchronously, and once the content is fetched, i call `jwplayer.setup(config)`, followed by `jwplayer.play()`.

Listening to the "playAttemptFailed" event, i get the following error: "303210 - The play attempt was interrupted for unknown reasons".

If i set 'mute' as 'true' in the `jwplayer.setup()`, then everything works, which makes me believe it is related to the autoplay policies.

Is there any way to remedy this? It should not be treated as autoplay, since the user interaction (play button click) did indeed happen, right?

This only happens on iOS.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on IOS device, so I fixed calling the jwplayer when the site is loaded and call `play` function on click event:

```js
    var player = null;
    var playerButton = document.getElementById('buttonPlayer');

    function initializePlayer() {
       player = jwplayer.setup({ file: '<STREAMING_URL>'});
    }

    function playButtonFunction() {
       player.play(true);
    }

    playerButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
       playButtonFunction();
    });

    window.addEventListener('load' , function() {
       initializePlayer();
    });
```